# Simple question about relative primes in entire rings.

Tags: ring-theory, factoring

Let $A$ be an entire ring. Let $a,b\in A$. Does

> The g.c.d. of $a,b$ is a multiplicative unit. $\Rightarrow$ $\langle a,b\rangle=A$

hold? If yes, how can I proof it?

Comment: You meant a [gcd domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain) ? In $k[x,y]$, $(1)$ is the smallest principal ideal containing $(x,y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False, e.g. $\,\gcd(x,y)=1\,$ in $\,\Bbb Q[x,y]\,$ but $\,(x,y)\neq (1)$ else eval $\,xf\! +\!yg=1\,$ at $\,x,y=0\,$  $\,\Rightarrow 0 = 1.\ $